# rhino mocks, return value of stub should depend on input

Tags: rhino-mocks

I'm looking for a clean way of letting the return value of a stub depend on its input.

At the moment im using the following approach, which doesn't scall well.

```
metadataLogic.Expect(x => x.GetMake(args.Vehicle1.Make)).Return(new CarMake { Id = args.Vehicle1.Make });
metadataLogic.Expect(x => x.GetMake(args.Vehicle2.Make)).Return(new CarMake { Id = args.Vehicle2.Make });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

When Stub return or stub actions should depend on arguments then you could use *Do handler* [few examples on github](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-mocks/blob/master/Rhino.Mocks.GettingStarted/Documentation/09-RhinoMocksTheDoHandler/09-RhinoMocksTheDoHandler/RhinoMocksTheDoHandlerTest.cs)

Regarding your example.
My assumptions are:
There are some class `CarMake` and interface `IMetadataLogic` like the following:

```c#
class CarMake
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

interface IMetadataLogic
{
    CarMake GetMake(string id);
}
```

And `metadataLogic` is

```c#
var metadataLogic = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMetadataLogic>();
```

If you need to just setup a Stub which returns `CarMake` instance with specified `Id` then you could do something like that:

```c#
metadataLogic
   .Stub(x => x.GetMake(Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
   .Do((Func<string, CarMake>)(id => new CarMake { Id = id }));
```

Unfortunately explicit cast lambda expression to delegate is necessary.

Please note stub in my example works for any argument but stub in your example works only for `args.Vehicle1.Make` and for `args.Vehicle2.Make`.

P.S.
If you need to just setup Stub you don't need to use `Expect()` method. You can use `Stub()` instead.